# Python Split String

Tags: python, regex, parsing, split

Lets Say we have `Zaptoit:685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com`

How do you split so it only be left `685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com`

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> s = 'Zaptoit:685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'
>>> s.split( ':', 1 )[1]
'685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'
```

Comment: Note that it's not really good practice to use the variable name "str" since str() is a builtin.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution:

```
s = 'Zaptoit:685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'
s.split(':', 1)[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another method, without using split:

```
s = 'Zaptoit:685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'
s[s.find(':')+1:]
```

Ex:

```
>>> s = 'Zaptoit:685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'
>>> s[s.find(':')+1:]
'685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Python 2.5 there is an even more direct solution.  It degrades nicely if the separator is not found:

```
>>> s = 'Zaptoit:685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'
>>> s.partition(':')
('Zaptoit', ':', '685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com')

>>> s.partition(':')[2]
'685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'

>>> s.partition(';')
('Zaptoit:685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com', '', '')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew about `split()`, but hadn't run across `partition()` before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following splits the string, ignores first element and rejoins the rest:

```
":".join(x.split(":")[1:])
```

Output:

```
'685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = re.sub('^.*?:', '', s)
```

Comment: @PEZ: better being stopping the match on the first ':' instead of the last one

Comment: @orip:  I think you are mistaken -- the question mark makes it a non-greedy match that will stop at the first colon, as intended

Comment: Yeah, I think Nick means something else.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case, but in general, if you have choice between a negated character class and a reluctant quantifier (eg, '.*?'), the char class tends to be faster, less memory-intensive, and most importantly, more predictable.

Comment: To me it's about clarity. Clearer is better. In this case .*?: is perfectly predictable and very clear. "Everything up to the first colon" is clearer than "Everything that's not a colon up to the first colon".

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tested the performance gain of using a negated character class compared to the non-greedy character, and thought the results could be interesting for others too: By doing the above operations 1000000 times in a loop, 3 times, and averaging the result, I rather consistently get a 13% decrease in execution time for the negated character class.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to compile the regexes outside the for loop. When doing this, the negated character class version takes 34% less time. I also tried to compile the code with cython, statically declaring the int:s and double:s (which should reduce overhead). Then time is reduced by 40%, so the negated character class clearly is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method str.split() with the value of maxsplit argument as 1.

```
mailID = 'Zaptoit:685158:zaptoit@hotmail.com' 
mailID.split(':', 1)[1]
```

Hope it helped.