# Split string into different variables instead of array in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Split String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436599/python-split-string)

Is possible to directly split string into variables in one line, instead of using two lines. I'm sure that split would have two elements.
Two lines example:

```
myString = "Anonym Anonymous"
a = myString.split()
firstName,lastName = a[0],a[1]
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write `firstName,lastName=myString.split()`?

Comment: @larsmans: It's not intended to be an answer.  I don't understand the question.  I'm hoping that an example will clarify what they're trying to ask.

Comment: But this is about python's syntax not about the function

Comment: Looking at this closed question, the number of views clearly indicates it's about something else, than existing duplicate question. This one is about python's syntax in combination with splitting of string, rather than splitting a string alone. One could deduce the answer from knowledge of two basic things, but this isn't a common case for complete python newbies, who are still learning - as I was 10 years ago,...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`firstName, lastName = myString.split()` should do it if you're sure it will return 2.

Better is `firstName, lastName = myString.split(' ', 1)`

Comment: What is better depends on the circumstances. If more or less than two values is an error, the first option is better as it will throw an appropriate exception.

Comment: Or `firstName, _, lastName = myString.partition(' ')`

Comment: I agree with larsmans.  I would usually prefer raise an exception when the input does not meet my expectations.

Answer (score 8):

```
firstname, lastname = "Anonym Anonymous".split()
```