# How do I delete the part of the string that I Specified

Tags: python, string

how should I delete everything on the string that starts with the letter I specify?

Let's say:

```
PHP/USD
```

I want to delete everything that starts with '/'  so what's left would be 'PHP'

and how do I do the reverse? Starts so that USD would be the only one left?

I only found answers on deleting the middle or deleting string that starts with something, but no a PART of the string. What is the better approach on this?

is it something with `oldstr.replace()` replace documentation that I have misread?

Comment: Can't you just split the string on the desired character? `first, second = myString.split("/")`

Comment: Tried `.split('/')[0]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into different variables instead of array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670290/split-string-into-different-variables-instead-of-array-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: I agree with cricket_007, use `"PHP/USD".split("/")[0]` to get PHP and `"PHP/USD".split("/")[-1]` to get USD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.sub` and replace the pattern `/.*$` with empty string:

```
import re
input = "PHP/USD"
line = re.sub(r"/.*$", "", input)
print line
# prints PHP
```

If you wanted the reverse, then use the pattern `^.*/`.