# splitting a string twice

Tags: python, string

I have a very large file and I want to split each row twice and return it. However I am only able to get the first result and the second is out of bounds

```
def clean_text(doc):
    rows = doc.split('\n')
    for row in rows:
        row = row.split('|')
        first_name = row[0]
        last_name = row[1] <---- out of bounds
        print(first_name, last_name)
```

Is there a nicer solution?

Comment: If you're getting an out of bounds error with `row[1]` then it means that `row.split('|')` returned a list of length=1 which means there was no pipe `|` in the line.

Comment: You *can* do `first_name, last_name = row.split('|')`, but that won't fix the out of bounds error. Perhaps add in a check before the split: `if '|' in row:`. Also you can do `doc.splitlines()` instead of splitting on `\n`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670290/split-string-into-different-variables-instead-of-array-in-python) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175800/pythonic-way-to-split-a-string-and-unpack-into-variables).

Comment: You could also catch the exception, or check the length returned..

Comment: You could also try ti solve the problem at the source, and make sure it always creates files with first and last names.

Comment: You need to add a check on the number of entries returned from the split. Often there are special cases in text files that don't quite conform to the expected pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do this check your resulting files and see all the ones without last name what is so special about them. From that point you can decide how to handle those cases.

If your input data(doc) is not something in your control than just reject if it is wrong or handle it by catching exception.
It is pointless for you to ask for best approach without specifying requirements and preconditions for your method.

```
def clean_text(doc):
    rows = doc.splitlines()
    for row in rows:
        row = row.split('|')
        first_name = row[0]
        try:
          last_name = row[1]
        except IndexError:
          last_name = ''
        print(first_name, last_name)
```