# How to cut the word across the middle in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = hello:world 

to

y = hello
z = world
```

So how i can cut that "hello:world" from that " : " mark to separately variables?

Sorry, this is a bit confusing because I can't explain it properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Split String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436599/python-split-string)

Comment: Is hello:world a string?

Comment: `y, z = x.split(':')`    split will return a list `['hello', 'world']`, and `x, y =` will unpack it

Comment: The code you posted there is not valid, can you please edit your code to make it runnable in order to clarify what you mean. If you mean x = "hello:world" then there are several examples here that should work

Comment: Metareven: I know it is not runnable... It is just bad example

Comment: Patrick Artner: Yes it is, but i just didnt know what to call that "split" thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
y, z = x.split(":")
```

Comment: Thanks that was fast :) And exactly what i wanted to!

Comment: @Texi You forgot to choose this as answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `split(expr)`, `expr` being the splitter.

```
hello, world = x.split(":")
```